# Get access to the information about the local machine

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, silverlight

I have an MVC3 project and need to know the information about the local machine such as RAM, Processor, Computer Name, System Type. Is it possible to get this information using JS or what kind of thechnology (web) can be used in order to obtain this information.
I know that it can be done by silverlight. Are there other ways?

Comment: Not possible without Silverlight, Flash or any other native plugin. Web Browsers always run JavaScript in sandbox where it has no access to any of machine information.

Comment: For security issues. You can't access clients system information through their web browser via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you will get more information here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/087ba8cc-f0e0-4497-aeb0-b79e35d832b8/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know it is possible with silverlight but the main goal is to get this information without silverlight